# What are the advantages/disadvantages of more rows in a radiator core?

Tags: cooling-system, jeep, radiator, cooling, terminology

When purchasing a radiator, one spec that is provided is the number of rows in the core.

I have a few closely related questions regarding these rows that are perhaps best to combine into this single post:

- First, exactly what defines a "row" within a radiator core?
- Second, what are the advantages/disadvantages of more rows in a radiator core?
- Third, is there any way to tell, from the outside, the number of rows in a radiator core?

Example of a Jeep radiator advertised as "1 row":
[image: 1 row radiator image]

Example of a Jeep radiator advertised as "2 rows":
[image: 2 row radiator image]

Example of a Jeep radiator advertised as "3 rows":
[image: 3 row radiator image]

Answer (score 3):

> First, exactly what defines a "row" within a radiator core?

The "row" is defined by the thickness of the radiator (front to back). A row means a row of tubing. It is sometimes hard to tell how many rows there are in a radiator by just looking at them. You would look down from the top and see a certain radiator is thicker to discern whether it is thicker than another. A three row radiator is pretty much going to fill the side tanks from front to back, where as a single row radiator will have a lot of space on the front and back side. (See image below.)

> Second, what are the advantages/disadvantages of more rows in a radiator core?

Pros:

- More cooling fin surface area
- More coolant to do the job

Cons:

- Cost
- Fitment may not be like a stock one. More than likely, work on the vehicle will need to occur in order for it to actually fit.
- Heavier weight to haul around (material + coolant)

**Note:** In another answer, it was stated it may take longer to get up to normal operating temperatures. This isn't quite accurate. If the thermostat in the engine is working properly, it won't take the engine any more time than normal to get up to operating temperature. It *will* take longer for the radiator to get hot, that's for sure, but not the engine.

> Third, is there any way to tell, from the outside, the number of rows in a radiator core?

As I stated, it's hard to really tell. I believe there is a measurement given with radiators which gives you the depth of the cross section of a radiator (i.e. front to back of the fin cross-section). This measurement would be the only layman's way to know. If you are completely familiar with what *should* go in a vehicle, you can judge how many rows a radiator has.

You can look a the following image and see a single core (bottom) and a multi-core (top). The red arrow shows you there's a space in the tank I'm talking about.

[image]

(Note: Pulled screen capture from a [video on YouTube](https://youtu.be/IqCX1RPAH2w))

Unless a vehicle is spec'd from the factory with different radiator sizes, more than likely they are a single row design. Vehicles, like the F-series Ford trucks, will have the same left/right and up/down dimensions to fit a radiator in the vehicle, but will need more cooling for an F-350 than it would for an F-150, so a thicker radiator with more cores may be needed. If the vehicle you're looking at doesn't have these different engine options, it won't have an OEM version with more cores for greater cooling. In this case, only an aftermarket radiator will work, but beware that aftermarket fitment may not be exact.

Comment: Thanks so much for the great answer.  What was confusing me so much was the terminology.  According to your answer, they aren't really rows... they are vertical columns.

Comment: Based on the info you provided, I added another con: weight.  If I'm mistaken, please just let me know.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket - I think that's more semantics then anything else. In the world of radiators, they are called "rows".

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket - I'd agree it'd weigh more, but really, the difference isn't going to be huge ... probably a couple of pounds (or kilos, depending on where you're from).

Comment: How much extra coolant do you think each row would hold (approx)?

Comment: Not a huge amount. The big thing is the extra tubes provides area for the fin stack to shed heat. The extra coolant is really inconsequential. the main mass of the coolant is contained inside the end tanks of the radiator and the engine. The amount is dependent upon the  cross section of the radiator (how big the frontal area is) as well as how big the tubes are. There's no "real" answer to that question because it's all dependent.

Answer (score 0):

The extra rows equate to more coolant capacity. More fluid in the radiator provides extra transfer of heat to the atmosphere. This may be a good thing if you Rock Crawl or plow snow or do high load low speed driving. In these situations, there is not as much air flow as driving at highway speed. The downside is extra cost,
and it may take longer to reach normal operating temp.